# null reference after LoadActiveScene()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I'm learning the basics of unity, I was creating a script that created an event and sent it to another script that called an audioclip

the function that activates the event, before sending it there is a check of the gameobject tag, then it adds +1 to a variable that is responsible for counting the points, destroys the object with which the player collided and finally activates the event

```
    public static event EventHandler audioCarrotPlay;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        switch(col.gameObject.tag){
            case tagColetaveis:
                _controleGame.Pontuacao(1);
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                audioCarrotPlay?.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
                
                
                break;

        }

    }
```

the second script is linked to an empty object that contains the audiosource component

```
{
    private AudioSource FxGame;
    [SerializeField]private AudioClip audioCarrot;
    void Start()
    {
        FxGame=gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Debug.Log(FxGame);
        ColetaColetaveis.audioCarrotPlay+=ColetaColetaveis_AudioCrrotPlay;
    }
    

    private void ColetaColetaveis_AudioCrrotPlay(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        
        Debug.Log("fxgame: "+FxGame);
        FxGame.PlayOneShot(audioCarrot);
        
    }
```

at first everything goes well and the audio was playing when picking up the object. after that I implemented a death to the player that when activated calls the LoadActiveScene() function

```
void CarregaJogo(){
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
```

that's when the problem started, in the first life everything runs fine, but after the player dies for the first time, unity starts to return a nullException, through debug I discovered that the null object is the FxGame audiosource, which is strange. the object is not null in the first debug (the one I did at start), but when the ColetaColetaveis_AudioCrrotPlay() function is called, the debug inside it says that now the FxGame is null.

The "solution" I found for this was to make FxGame static
`private static AudioSource FxGame;`

this made the audioSource work and be not null after the first death, but I don't want this variable as static

Answer (score 0):

after searching in several forums I found something promising, removing the subscriber's registration when the object was destroyed by LoadScene().

```
void OnDestroy(){
    ColetaColetaveis.audioCarrotPlay-=ColetaColetaveis_AudioCrrotPlay;
}
```

this function removes the inscription when the object is destroyed, apparently that was the problem because the object is no longer null and the sound effect is triggered